# Does solubility imply nilpotency?

Tags: gr.group-theory

**Def.** If $X\subseteq G$, we say that $X$ is $k$-large in $G$ if the intersection of any $k$ left translates of $X$ is non-empty. (See the notion of largeness which was introduced in ["Largeur et nilpotence"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870008826997).)

Let $G$ be a soluble group with derived length $n$, $p$ be a prime number and $\phi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ be of order $p$. Assume that

1. The set $\{x\in G: \prod_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{\phi^k}=1\}$ is $2^{n+1}$-large,
2. $G/G^{(n-1)}$ is nilpotent and its nilpotency class is $2^n$,
3. For all $x\in G$, $\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{\phi^k}\in G^{(n-1)}$.

Then is $G$ nilpotent (of nilpotency class $2^{n+1}$)?

($G^{(r)}$ stands for the $r$th derivation of $G$)

Comment: Can you please explain the motivation behind this question and why do you think it is true?

Comment: Isn't this false with $G=S_3$ and $\phi$ conjugation by an element of order $2$?

Comment: @YiftachBarnea The motivation is giving a new version of Theorem 13 of [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870008826997).

Comment: @DerekHolt, Thank you, I think you are right. I I have to rewrite my assumptions more accurately.

Comment: I think that condition 3 already implies that $G/G^{(n-1)}$ is nilpotent (applying a theorem of O. Kegel to $G/G^{(n-1)}$ with the automorphism induced by $\phi$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I do not know about that theorem, could you please provide me a reference?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan: See this question, for what I think Geoff is referring to: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384175/what-is-known-about-the-structure-of-finite-groups-admitting-an-automorphism-whe)

Comment: @spin : Yes, thanks, that is the theorem I refer to, and there is a full reference to Kegel's paper in the accepted answer..